# Как указать пути к файлам csv для pandas jupiter

Tags: python-3.x

Файл с данными с расширением csv C:\Users\14155\Documents___Skillbox\pandas
Как его указать в функции pandas.read_csv(). Функция используется в  script python jupiter

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(r “C:\Users\14155\Documents___Skillbox\pandas.csv”)